# Is there a way to combine two list which will have second list element into each and every sublist in first one?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-8, java-stream

Here is my code which will return combined list :

```
List<Map<String, Object>> viewList = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
List<Map<String, Object>> viewList1 = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();

Map<String, Object> viewMap1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
viewMap1.put("ARTICLE_ID", "000000001000100126");
viewMap1.put("SOURCE_ID", "0000007001");
viewMap1.put("UOM", "CS");

Map<String, Object> viewMap2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
viewMap2.put("ARTICLE_ID", "000000001000100126");
viewMap2.put("SOURCE_ID", "0000007001");
viewMap2.put("UOM", "EA");

Map<String, Object> viewMap3 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
viewMap3.put("ARTICLE_ID", "000000001000100126");
viewMap3.put("SOURCE_ID", "0000007001");
viewMap3.put("UOM", "YD2");

Map<String, Object> viewMap4 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
viewMap4.put("BASEQUANTITY", "3");

viewList.add(viewMap1);
viewList.add(viewMap2);
viewList.add(viewMap3);

viewList1.add(viewMap4);

List<Map<String, Object>> combinedList = Stream.of(viewList, viewList1)
                                               .flatMap(x -> x.stream())
                                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(combinedList);
```

**I am getting Output as follows:**

> [{UOM=CS, SOURCE_ID=0000007001, ARTICLE_ID=000000001000100126}, {UOM=EA, SOURCE_ID=0000007001, ARTICLE_ID=000000001000100126}, {UOM=YD2, SOURCE_ID=0000007001, ARTICLE_ID=000000001000100126}, {BASEQUANTITY=3}]

**I want the output like:**

> [{UOM=CS, SOURCE_ID=0000007001, ARTICLE_ID=000000001000100126, BASEQUANTITY=3}, {UOM=EA, SOURCE_ID=0000007001, ARTICLE_ID=000000001000100126, BASEQUANTITY=3}, {UOM=YD2, SOURCE_ID=0000007001, ARTICLE_ID=000000001000100126, BASEQUANTITY=3}]

How to add last element i.e. BASEQUANTITY=3 of `combinedList` into each and every subList of first List and remove that element from `combinedList` as showing in above output. Please help.

Comment: Why is the second map in a list at all? Seems like all you want is to copy the one entry into all lists from `viewList`?

Comment: @ernest_k , There is a requirement as we need to combine 2 list of maps.

Comment: Do you want this?  List<Map<String, Object>> combinedList = viewList.stream().map(x -> x.putAll(viewMap4)).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: @Preston, I am not sure it is throwing me an error. Can you please verify your answer.

Comment: Updates:  List<Map<String, Object>> combinedList = viewList.stream().map(x -> {
  x.putAll(viewMap4);
  return x;
 }).collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 1):

Don't stream both of them together as it looks like you need every key-value pair of every map in your second list to be added to every map in the first list.

````java
// first add everything from viewList to combinedList
List<Map<String, Object>> combinedList = new ArrayList<>(viewList);

// Now for every map in combinedList (which is now equivalent to viewList),
// add contents of every map from viewList1 to combinedList.
combinedList.forEach(map -> viewList1.forEach(map2 -> map.putAll(map2)));

or,
```java
combinedList.forEach(map -> viewList1.forEach(map::putAll));
````

**EDIT:**
Even though addition/deletion of elements in the `combinedList` won't be reflected in `viewList`, as [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68907236/7804477) pointed out, any changes to elements of the map within `combinedList` will be reflected in the maps of `viewList` (as `new ArrayList<>(viewList)` is used to create the `combinedList`).

In order to avoid this, `combinedList` could be initialized as:

```java
List<Map<String, Object>> combinedList = viewList.stream().map(HashMap::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Can you please brief your answer I want the result of combinedList as in List<Map<String, Object>>

Comment: @VikramAditya I have updated the answer. Hope it is clear now

Answer (score 0):

[The solution offered by @Gautham M](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68707923/13279831) affects `viewList` - because `combinedList` is created as a shallow copy of `viewList` and both lists refer the same maps.  Thus, when adding the contents of `viewList1` to each map in `combinedList`, it also "appears" in `viewList`.

Also, in general case if it is needed to add the contents of all entries of all maps in `viewList1`, this list should be flatten into a single map and then this *subtotal* map is added to the copies of maps in `viewList`:

```java
Map<String, Object> subtotal = viewList1
    .stream()
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey, 
        Map.Entry::getValue, 
        (v1, v2) -> v1 // resolve possible conflicts by keeping the first value
    ));

List<Map<String, Object>> combinedList = viewList
    .stream() // Stream<Map>
    .map(HashMap::new) // copy map is created
    .peek(copy -> copy.putAll(subtotal))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println("combined:\n" + combinedList);

System.out.println("\ninitial:\n" + viewList);
```

Output

> combined:
> [{BASEQUANTITY=3, UOM=CS, SOURCE_ID=0000007001, ARTICLE_ID=000000001000100126}, {BASEQUANTITY=3, UOM=EA, SOURCE_ID=0000007001, ARTICLE_ID=000000001000100126}, {BASEQUANTITY=3, UOM=YD2, SOURCE_ID=0000007001, ARTICLE_ID=000000001000100126}]
>
> initial:
> [{UOM=CS, SOURCE_ID=0000007001, ARTICLE_ID=000000001000100126}, {UOM=EA, SOURCE_ID=0000007001, ARTICLE_ID=000000001000100126}, {UOM=YD2, SOURCE_ID=0000007001, ARTICLE_ID=000000001000100126}]